# Call function from different coffeescript file in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

votable.coffee:

```
set_votable_hooks = (vote_area_name) ->
  ...
```

questions.coffee:

```
vote_area_name = 'xyz'
$(document).ready(set_votable_hooks(vote_area_name))
```

I want function to be called on document ready. I know that every coffee file is placed inside a function, so its contents are not available inside other. I've read that solution is to make set_votable_hooks global or use namespaces, couldn't manage them to work, because I'm new to js. But as I understand, preferred solution is to use namespaces in order to not pollute global object.

Answer (score 4):

Discovered, that first my mistake was assigning to callback - function with parameter, so I ended up with:

votable.coffee:

```
window.Votable ?= {}

window.Votable.set_votable_hooks = (vote_area_name) ->
  ...
```

questions.coffee:

```
load_votable = ->
  window.Votable.set_votable_hooks('.question-vote-area')

$(document).ready(load_votable)
```

and redefined coffee file inclusion in application.js:

```
...
//= require votable
//= require_tree .
...
```

without last step questions included on page before votable